# It's mysql or mysqld?

Tags: mysql, database, difference

recently I've installed Mysql and it turns out the service name of it is "mysql" (there no "d" suffix), I remember before this time it's "mysqld" all the time. And when you type in "sudo service mysqld status" it would say this service does not exists.

Is there any difference between this two? Or it's a total diffrent version of mysql?

Comment: Which distro? Also, what's the CLI tool is called then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"d" stands for "daemon" and this is the server service. `mysql` is the command-line client program. This is for Windows and Linux, didn't test for other OSes

Answer (score 9):

Don't worry about service names - they can be customized... by default, `mysql` takes MySQL as service names on windows machines.

If you want to change the service on either machine, just uninstall the service..

```
/path/to/mysql/bin/mysqld --remove mysql
```

Now, you can rename it... say Neelima

```
/path/to/mysql/bin/mysqld --install Neelima
```

Now you will see a service name called Neelima for MySQL server...

Back to the difference between `mysql` & `mysqld` (forget service names here) --

`mysql` -- a command-line client for executing SQL statements interactively or in batch mode.

`mysqld` -- the MySQL server.

Answer (score 5):

Mysqld = Mysql + D

***D*** stands for **Daemon**

Pronounced DEE-mun or DAY-mun. Daemon is  a process that runs in the background and performs a specified operation at predefined times or in response to certain events.

Hope it clears MySqld

**mysql** -- A command-line client for executing SQL statements Like Terminal in ubuntu

Answer (score 4):

'Mysql' is the client program , while mysqld is the server instance--the 'd' in mysqld stands for daemon.

Before running a mysql program, the mysqld server has to be running. You first start the server from the command line by typing "mysqld" then you connect the client typing -- "mysql -u root -p password"

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora 28, there is no difference. Namely, both 'systemctl status mysqld' and
`systemctl status mysql' output exactly the same. But this is about the services.
As regards the commands named 'mysqld'  and 'mysql', I stick with what has been said
here by others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  Like Ubuntu Linux mysqld  is Server while mysql is client to connect to server

- mysqld is the server executable (one of them)
- mysql is the command line client

link : [Difference between mysql, mysqladmin, mysqld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132780/difference-between-mysql-mysqladmin-mysqld)

http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Linux/Q_26697809.html