# What does the d mean in mysqld.exe

Tags: mysql, server

What does the "d" mean in `mysqld.ex`e? I think I have seen it in other software, too. `httpd`, for example. They also use `%d.exe` to start the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between mysql, mysqladmin, mysqld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132780/difference-between-mysql-mysqladmin-mysqld)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `d` is short for `daemon`. Basically a deamon is a background process (no UI) that responds to a request.

See https://searchmicroservices.techtarget.com/definition/daemon.

More info at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39266/what-is-the-difference-between-daemon-and-demon-in-a-religious-context

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that `mysqld` and `httpd` are the processes for MySQL & HTTP SERVERS, that are hosted off of the machine - not just a random MySQL process. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld.html

I'm not entirely sure about this but I believe the 'd' stands for 'daemon' - being a process that runs continually in the background of the host machine and receives requests which it then forwards to other processes. (Such as http requests or SQL queries)